# Learn Python the Hard Way - EX 41 - Invalid Syntax

Tags: python, syntax-error

I keep receiving SyntaxError message on ex41.py OR oop_test.py, and I've run through the whole script, everything is exactly as it is in the book, but I keep getting this - the variable {answer} is seemingly only defined in the try: section, so I have no clue why I am getting this SyntaxError.

`***:hardway ***$ python ex41.py english
  File "ex41.py", line 76
    print(f"ANSWER: {answer}\n\n")
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Here is the try: section, where the variable is at:

```
try:
    while True:
        snippets = list(PHRASES.keys())
        random.shuffle(snippets)

        for snippet in snippets:
            phrase = PHRASES[snippet]
            question, answer = convert(snippet, phrase)
            if PHRASE_FIRST:
                question, answer = answer, question

            print(question)

            input("> ")
            print(f"ANSWER: {answer}\n\n")

except EOFError:
    print("\nBye") `
```

The entirety of the code can be found here: [Learning Python The hard way Ex. 41 - Learning to Speak Object-Oriented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46135191/learning-python-the-hard-way-ex-41-learning-to-speak-object-oriented)

Comment: Please use python3.6 to run this code, where `f` strings are first introduced.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine.  The problem is the Python version you are running.

As mentioned in the comments above f strings were first introduced in Python 3.6 (see [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-498-formatted-string-literals)). If you want to use this feature you need to update to Python 3.6.

If you do not (or cannot) switch version you can use `format()` instead:

```
  print("ANSWER: {}\n\n".format(answer))
```

OR use the old style `%s` (formatting string) operator:

```
  print("ANSWER: %s\n\n" %answer)
```

See: [What does %s mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997797/what-does-s-mean-in-python)

I would suggest `format()` over the second method though.

If you are making code that will be run on Python versions before Python 3.6 it it a good idea to use the alternatives listed above.

Comment: haha, I'm pretty novice, and this definitely worked...lesson learned.

Comment: @SamParsons  Since you are still learning Python, can I suggest you update to Python 3.6 (or the latest version) so that you get all the newest features, but if you can't never mind...